# How to solve error "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: session" when running Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I've installed Apache Airflow version 2.2.4 on my system Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS and I'm using these steps

- export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow
- pip3 install apache-airflow
- airflow db init
- airflow users create --username admin --firstname XXXX --lastname XXX --role Admin --email XXX@gmail.com

When I'm running my server using this command

- airflow webserver -p 8080

I've got an error saying

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: session

[image: apacheAirflow]

How can I solve this error?

Comment: yes you can see in step 3 ```airflow db init```

Answer (score 4):

For me the issue was that I have set the `AIRFLOW_HOME` on one tab of my terminal, but on the other tab (from where I was running the webserver) I forgot to set it. So the solution is to do the following in **ALL TERMINAL TABS** that you're using for Airflow:

1. Activate the virtual environment where your Airflow is installed

   ```
   source your_airflow_venv/bin/activate
   ```
2. Navigate to the directory where your Airflow project is

   ```
   cd /path_to_your_airflow_dir
   ```
3. Update your `AIRFLOW_HOME` environment variable

   ```
   export AIRFLOW_HOME=$(pwd)
   ```
4. Initialize the Airflow database

   ```
   airflow db init
   ```
5. Start the Airflow Web Server or the Airflow Scheduler (depending on which terminal tab you currently are)

   ```
   airflow scheduler
   airflow webserver
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Before running webserver using command `airflow webserver`, make sure to set AIRFLOW_HOME using below command:

```
 export AIRFLOW_HOME="your_airflow_directory"
```

Comment: i did try this still getting the same error?

Comment: Then try doing a db reset using command : airflow db reset after setting the above. variable. and try doing the airflow db init.  Also. make sure to set same AIRFLOW_HOME  before running these commands

Comment: it's not working geeting the same result again seems like there is some problem with session id? ```[SQL: SELECT session.id AS session_id_1, session.session_id AS session_session_id, session.data AS session_data, session.expiry AS session_expiry 
FROM session 
WHERE session.session_id = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: ('347fde8a-01bc-4074-9f3c-87f1dc7ec4de', 1, 0)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)```

Comment: try a fresh installation, that would be last resort

Comment: I did I installed it again using a different directory but still getting the same error? I don't know what when wrong? I can't even find solution online

Comment: happened to me, try creating virtual environment and installing airflow there, or else use airflow docker image and run it inside docker container, that should help
Docker link : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html

Comment: @iamhimanshu0 - facing similar issue - were you able to figure it out?

Comment: The reason in my case was airflow installation in the default directory and then I trying to change the airflow_home , what I did was changed the airflow_home first to point to the virtual environment where I installed airflow. After that I did a db reset and db init and create a user. That should be it, key here is to first set AIRFLOW_HOME variable to point to the right directory before metadata DB is installed (sqlite in my case).
Also before running airflow web server and scheduler make sure the terminal has right AIRFLOW_HOME env variable set

Comment: @ANURAGBISHT not working I did this also but still the same...

Comment: How about using a docker image and spinning it up using docker composer on local environment ? Does that work ? @iamhimanshu0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. I made the mistake and naively installed airflow through pip.

I fixed the issue by deleting the directory AIRFLOW_HOME points to and [reinstalling airflow through pip with a constraint](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html). Then I initiated the automated airflow setup with the `airflow standalone` command.